# Certificate not accepted. Unable to set private key file

Tags: php, soap, certificate, pem, pfx

I try to make a connection through SoapClient. I need a certificate for this. I received a .pfx certificate. I used the following command to create a .pem file.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out cert.pem -nodes
```

There is a password in the certificate so I need to enter it before I get the cert.pem file. So far so good, I think.

Now I try to connect to the WSDL service.

```
$url = "https://test.website.com/webservices/transfer.asmx?WSDL";
$cert = '/path/to/cert.pem';
$passphrase = "12345678";                                               

$soapClient = new SoapClient($url, array('local_cert'=>$cert,'passphrase'=>$passphrase));
```

I get the following error:

> (Warning) SoapClient::SoapClient(): Unable to set private key file `/var/www/vhosts/............./cert.pem'

I think the problem is the certificate. Is the way that I converted the .pfx to a .pem the correct way?

Comment: I still got problem whit this. Found this. 

note: including the "-nodes" flag here will prevent using a passphrase to encrypt the private key(s).

Whit or without the passphrase i get the same error.

Comment: is that cert the public or private one?

Comment: why did you use `-nodes` rather than `-clcerts`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that a `.pem` certificate is always supposed to be an encrypted file. According to the [OpenSSL docs for the pkcs12 command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/pkcs12.html) when you used `-nodes` it didn't encrypt anything, rather put each node into plain text, which caused the `.pem` certificate to be invalid and your `SoapClient` couldn't parse the invalid file.

To fix this, hopefully you haven't deleted the original `cert.pfx`, just re-convert it using this line:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out cert.pem -clcerts
```

and your `cert.pem` file will be correct.

Comment: You are my favourite person today! TY! After trying a hundred and one way get the right certs, this finally did it. Then `$soapClient = new \SoapClient($wsdl, ['local_cert' => 'cert.pem', 'passphrase' => 'Entered PEM pass phrase', 'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0]);` and you can retrieve all given methods with `$soapClient->__getFunctions();`

Answer (score 3):

Today I had this problem with an invalid Cert/Private combination, meaning the cert wasn't belonging to the specified key.

**You can verify this problem using:**

```
openssl rsa  -noout -modulus -in server.key | openssl md5
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.crt | openssl md5
```

key and cert should return the same checksum. If not, somebody has mixed up some files.

The same procedure works for CSRs as well:

```
# and for a CSR
openssl req -noout -modulus -in server.csr | openssl md5
```